# BigQuery - what is the difference between enforced vs not enforced primary key?

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery - what is the difference between enforced vs not enforced primary key?

Looked over the documentation and didn't find something clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery as of this writing supports only NO enforced keys. Documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-constraints#limitations) as limitations.

Essentially this means duplicate values are accepted.

Comment: Thanks. I can't understand the use of "no enforce PK". Do you see one?

Comment: It means the feature exists for syntax compatibility, but data is inserted even if there is a duplicate key. Other databases won't let you to insert duplicate data.

Comment: I understand.. but why did they add a PK that behaves a normal column?